# How do I track Virtual Pageviews in the new version of GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I've attempted to use the new version of Google Tag Manager to track virtual pageviews and send those to Google Analytics, but they don't seem to be sending properly.

For my Trigger, I've used the builtin History Change event type and have placed that in a tag with my Google Analytics id. The tag is set to Page View track type.

In Google Analytics, I see a pageview, but it just says the user is on the root directory. Also, I'm working in Localhost.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: I think you missed a full description of your setup. I take it this is some kind of one-page application ?

Comment: It is. What else would you like to know?

Comment: On localhost you'd have to set the cookie domain field to none. As a bit of guessing (hence a comment rather than an answer), I guess you'd have to set the page path field to the "New History Fragment" macro to get a value different from the root url.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to get the complete description of your setup but maybe an other way of tracking your virtual pageview could be directly by adding data layers directly in your code.

```
dataLayer.push({
'event':'VirtualPageview',
'virtualPageURL':'/order/step1',
'virtualPageTitle' : 'Order Step 1 – Contact Information'
});
```

For the trigger, you will then be able to send the fire on of your virtual pageview as a event matches VirtualPageview.

Your Tag need to be set up as a pageview.

Also, using this article for GTM v1 : http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/09/10/fire-virtual-pageview-google-tag-manager/, you can set up your {{virtualPageURL}}

In GTM V2, in your tag, you will have to use the - More settings / Field to set field Name = Page, Value = {{virtualPageURL}}.

Are we talking here about a one page iOS/Android App?

Comment: Excellent answer! Exactly what I was looking for!
Thanks Mick!
Just one thing though, in case one wishes to set the page URL as static (For ex: Triggering 'Tag1' for click on 'button1' and having a fixed url like '/abc/xyz'), then you need not even write the dataLayer.push() code.
Just create your tag as a PageView with "Fields to set", Name="page", and Value="/abc/xyz". This also gets the job done.